# Is survey participation a cause of survey response?

Tags: causality, survey, causal-diagram

I am rewatching [Statistical Rethinking 2023 - 11 - Ordered Categories](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VVQaIkom5D0)
 because McElreath mentions some causal assumptions about survey responses, which I am interested in. He proposes a causal diagram for a survey. In this diagram Participation (in the survey) is included to illustrate a collider being conditioned on to open backdoor paths.

[image]

But I also wonder if it makes sense that Participation itself would be a cause of Survey Response. If a participant doesn't participate that would cause missingness of a survey response, which seems like a valid counterfactual claim about causality.

[image]

Is survey participation a cause of survey response? Or have I misunderstood how to assign causes in this case?